# "Cannot create a QWidget without QApplication" in plt.figure() in Python's matplotlib when used in combination with ovito library

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code, executed with Python 3.8, fails

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ovito

plt.figure()
# QWidget: Cannot create a QWidget without QApplication
# [1]    97753 abort
```

The ovito library is fully operational. Naturally, `plt.figure()` works when ovito is not imported. The error does not change when reversing the import statements.

What can be causing this error, and is there a workaround? It seems that both libraries try to create a QWidget, but there can only be one at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late but I ran into the same issue.

I solved it with a workaround using `multiprocessing`:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def use_ovito(some_argument=None):
    import ovito
    # Use Ovito
    print(f"I have {ovito}. {some_argument}")


def invoke(some_argument):
    p = Process(target=use_ovito, args=(some_argument,))
    p.start()
    print("Waiting...")
    p.join()
    print("Done")


def main():
    invoke("Hello")
    plt.figure() # Works!


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

(Tested on python 3.10.12)